# Dynamic events added to dynamic textboxes not triggering

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, dynamic, textbox

I'm wanting to add some dynamic textboxs to a table and have them trigger an event.
I'm having no problem creating the textboxs, or accessing the information about them, but they  do not want to trigger the event.

```
    List<string> txtNames = new List<string>();
    txtNames.Add("txtId");
    txtNames.Add("txtName");
    txtNames.Add("txtQty");
    txtNames.Add("txtUnitPrice");
    txtNames.Add("txtExtendedPrice");

    Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("\t<tr>\n"));
    TextBox txt;
    foreach (string s in txtNames)
    {
        txt = new TextBox();
        txt.CopyBaseAttributes(Textbox1);
        txt.Text = "";
        txt.BorderWidth = 0;
        txt.ID = s + row;

        Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("\t\t<td>"));
        Panel1.Controls.Add(txt);
        Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td>\n"));

        txt.AutoPostBack = true;
        txt.TextChanged += new EventHandler(txt_TextChanged);

        txt.Text = s;
        count++;
    }
    Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("\t</tr>\n"));
    row++;
```

(the panel is inside a html table)

This code is in a function that is called when the page is not post back or when a button is clicked to add a row of textboxes.

The text boxes are saved to a session then reloaded on page_load.

I've tried making an test textbox that was not created in a for loop and that one does trigger the text change event.

**Edit**:
I tried re-adding the text change event when loaded the textboxes from the saved session and now they are triggering the function.

Comment: Where is the code above located? Page_Load?

Comment: Its in a function that is called when the page is not post back, or when i click a button to add an other row of text boxes.

Comment: Is the test textbox which works also saved and recreated?

Comment: No its created every time on the page load event.

Answer (score 1):

You should place you method call inside OnInit instead of pageload, and set the Text property only when not post back

```
   protected override void OnInit( EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        int row = 0;
        int count = 0;
        List<string> txtNames = new List<string>();
        txtNames.Add("txtId");
        txtNames.Add("txtName");
        txtNames.Add("txtQty");
        txtNames.Add("txtUnitPrice");
        txtNames.Add("txtExtendedPrice");

        Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("\t<tr>\n"));
        TextBox txt;
        foreach (string s in txtNames)
        {
            txt = new TextBox();
            //txt.CopyBaseAttributes(Textbox1);
            txt.BorderWidth = 0;
            txt.ID = s + row;

            Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("\t\t<td>"));
            Panel1.Controls.Add(txt);
            Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td>\n"));

            txt.AutoPostBack = true;
            txt.TextChanged += (sndr, evt) => { Response.Write(((Control)sndr).ID + " --- " + ((TextBox)sndr).Text); };

            if(!IsPostBack)
                txt.Text = s;
            count++;
        }
        Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("\t</tr>\n"));
        row++;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The controls and events should be recreated in Page_Load, because the dynamic controls are lost after request.

Comment: I am saving them to a session and then reloading them on Page_load

Comment: I'm finding all the textboxes, saving them to a list and saving that list to a session. Then to load i just take that list of textboxes and add them back in almost exactly the same way.